# New() method used in class definition to return a new object of itself in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, methods, new-operator

I'm studying this snippet:

```
def self.from_file(file_name)
  new(File.readlines(file_name))
end
```

How does this code work? Does it only work for class methods? I understand this is supposed to return a new object of the class it was defined in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` in Ruby is not an operator, it is simply a method from [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) so you're just calling the `new` method with the class as the implicit receiver, you could also say:

```
self.new(File.readlines(file_name))
```

if you wanted to be explicit about what you're doing. As far as what it does, it:

> Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*’s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method [...]. This is the method that ends up getting called whenever an object is constructed using `.new`.

Comment: It's an instance method of `Class`, not a class method of `BasicObject`. `BasicObject` just happens to an instance of `Class`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Right, I had my references mixed up was hurrying out the door.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby sends messages that do not have an explicit receiver to the currently scoped 'self' receiver by default. Scope in ruby is all about what object represents self. Because the method is defined as self.method the scope for the method is the class object where the method is defined. Because the new message does not have an explicit receive it is sent to self, which in this case is the class containing the method.